# How to get integer keys in insertion order in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, redux

I'm using **react-redux** to build an app so i'm unable to use **LinkedHashMap**.

I would like to be able to iterate over the integer key'ed `{[x: number]: string}` object in their insertion order.

Keys require to be integers as the keys would be id's of objects from database.

Comment: You can't. The language spec stipulates that numeric (integer) property names are iterated in numeric order. If you need to do that, you'll need to construct your own mechanism to track insertion order.

Comment: If the order matters, consider using an array

Comment: I'm currently using an array to store keys alongside the original object. This solves my problem.